# How do I delete symlinks from a Windows folder with a batch file/script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, symbolic-link

How do I delete all symlinks and only all symlinks from a folder with a batch file/script?

The folder is `c:\wamp\www`, and this is what I've tried:

Content files delete.cmd

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ("dir /a:l /s /b c:\wamp\www") do (
rmdir c:\wamp\www\%%D
)
```

But my code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the symlink (even folder symlinks) as the file they are and not a folder:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %a IN (`DIR /a:l /s /b "."`) DO del "%a"
```

If you're working with hardlinks, that's a bit harder, to detect use something like

```
`find "." -links +1`
```

in your for loop to find the hardlinks.